# VSCode - Add filetype icons to QuickPick list

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a Visual Studio Code extension which uses a QuickPick list.

I saw that I can use octicons in order to add icons to the list items, 
however I would like to add the filetype icons to the list items (like in workbench.actions.quickOpen [for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rLyU.png)).

Is there a way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. There was a request for better image support at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/16445, thuogh that's been closed as a duplicate of https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79130 (which seems to be for extending/replacing all icons).